# Eloquent query is returning everything even with my where statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get some info from 2 tables with eloquent and its relationships with Constraining Eager Loads in Laravel 5.1, but it always returns everything even when the 'where' is searching for a non-existing value

This is the code:

```
$selectedImages = ImageSession::with(['folder' => function($query){
    $query->where('session', Session::getId());
}])->get();
```

I would like to also learn how to specify the select columns for this statement.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query only restricts the folders, but not image sessions.

Use the `whereHas` method to restrict the main model too:

```php
$constraint = function ($query) {
    $query->where('session', Session::getId());
};

$selected = ImageSession::with(['folder' => $constraint])
                        ->whereHas('folder', $constraint)
                        ->get();
```

Comment: Ohhh I see, thanks that worked. Is there a way to put this in a single block?

Comment: Nope. You can either write the closure twice or do it the way I've shown you.